# Overloading C++

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm defining a class Integer in my homework

```
class Integer
{
    int value;
public:
    Integer() {}
    Integer(int val) { this->value = val; }
    void operator =(int val) { this->value = val; }
};

int main(void)
{
    Integer a;
    Integer* p = new Integer[2];
    a = 1;
    p[a]; // <-- I want to define this
    return 0;
}
```

So how do I define `p[a]`?

Sorry, my English is not good.

Comment: could u add more details, then

Comment: Do you mean the multiplication operator? `*`

Comment: `void operator =` you mean `Integer& operator =`

Comment: You can find the canonical form of every overloadable operator [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) - but they should also be described in any good book.

Comment: Are you asking for conversion Integer -> int ?

Comment: Your default constructor leaves `value` uninitialized. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: @Eljay - he is talking about the derefrence operator `*` not the multiplication !!

Comment: `p[a]` is strange because *a* is an *Integer*

Comment: Always use the constructors initialization list in preference over the constructor body when you can. `Integer(int val) { this->value = val; }` is better written as `Integer(int val) : value(val) { }`

Comment: Error is "operand types are: Integer *[Integer]". Can I define it?

Comment: If you want to use an `Integer` as an index, you need an implicit conversion to `int`, which will be a [user-defined conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: Your English is fine by the way, but the question is unclear because you show an expression with two operands, and the operator is shows is not the one you want to implement. The `operator[]` part is handled the same as any other pointer.

Comment: @PhúNguyễn if you want to have the form `p[a]` valid you need to define the conversion Integer -> `int` (or `size_t`) or the dereference operator `*`. *But* are you sure you want that ? seems strange

Comment: It is my homework. My teachers always ask such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscript operator can only be overloaded as a member function and not as a free function.

As such, there is no way to define a subscript operator overload for non class types such as `Integer*`.

What you could do is make your class implicitly convertible to a fundamental integer type. That way, you would be using the normal pointer subscript operator that accepts pointer and integer. This can be achieved by defining a conversion operator.